# Group child content types under their parent content type in the same list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-type, list-view, grouping

the title pretty much says what I need. Let's say I have two list items derived from two custom content types with the following fields:

```
ContentType1
ID: 1
Title: "Item1"

ContentType2
ID: 2
Title: "Item2"
ParentItem: "1;#Item1"
```

Is it possible to group these in my custom list schema so I would end up with something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible! meanwhile, You can group by content type to show your list as shown below

[image]

By editing your viwe schema in sharepoint designer and set query section as

```
<GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30"><FieldRef Name="ContentType"/></GroupBy>
```

for more details check [GROUP BY CONTENT-TYPE IN SHAREPOINT LIST VIEW](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/04/22/group-by-content-type-in-sharepoint-list-view/)